# Database query taking forever to load

Tags: mysql, sql, database, joomla, joomla3.0

I have a query that I'm trying to create but it takes forever for the page to load when the query is active...

What I'm trying to do is:

I have a video website, and when you click on a video, you are redirected to the VIDEO page where you can see the video and the url structure is like this:

www.site.com/VIDEO_CATEGORY_NAME/VIDEO_ID.html

The video_category and video_id are in separate tables.

What I'm trying to achieve is: make a link so when user clicks it will get redirected to a RANDOM video page (random video).

Here is the query I'm trying to write:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT distinct a.*,b.category FROM #__hdflv_upload a LEFT JOIN #__hdflv_category b on a.playlistid=b.id or a.playlistid=b.parent_id WHERE a.published='1' and b.published='1' and b.id=" . $videocategory1 . " and a.id != " .$videoid1 ." order by rand()";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
```

and the link:

```
<a href="/player/<?php echo $result; ?>.html">random video</a>
```

When the query is on the page it takes forever to load the page...
Can somebody give me a hand please. Thank you

Comment: Output the query, run `EXPLAIN <the query>` in phpmyadmin and edit your question to insert the output.

Comment: it writes: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 :(

Comment: Have you replace the table names? They seem to be placeholders, replaced by your database abstraction layer.

Comment: That's how usually the tables are called in Joomla, but I tried with the full table name too and it's the same thing :( Logically is the query correctly written?

Comment: Yes, the query seems correct. Prepended with `EXPLAIN` it should return the detailed execution plan. This will reveal at least a `filesort`, because you `ORDER BY RAND()`, but will also reveal if the query uses indices, which one cannot infer from seeing the code.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to execute as a query in PMA right now?

Comment: I tried prepending EXPLAIN before the SELECT but it writes the same thing "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1" nothing changes :(

Comment: I can give you access to the phpmyadmin if you want?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to execute as a query in PMA right now?

Comment: @Turophile Your statement is wrong. Try it.

Comment: I'm trying to get a CORRRECT random video_category and video_id, by correct I mean that video_id must be valid in video_category, for example category A = video_id (1,2,3) and category B = video_id(3,4,5)

so if I randomly get the category A, the video_id must be randomly thorugh id1,2 or 3 only, because video_id 3,4 or 6 are at category B...

Comment: yes I removed the "" while testing the query in phpmyadmin

Comment: @GhostGambler, you are correct - my experience is mostly with DB2, which is different. I will delete the misleading comment.

Comment: @AlexandruVlas I asked you to copy&paste the query into a comment. Not to explain in natural language, what you want to achieve.

Comment: 1 sec, I changed the table names from #__ to full table name and I get it working with explain, will put a screenshot here

Comment: http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/i3/537f4289de0af9-55814050

Comment: Looking at the query you do a JOIN with an OR in the ON clause ( `on a.playlistid=b.id or a.playlistid=b.parent_id ` ). This is almost certain to result in any index on the table #__hdflv_category being ignored for the join. Further you are checking values on #__hdflv_category in the WHERE clause which renders the LEFT OUTER JOIN to be an INNER JOIN. By the way, your screen shot is too small to read.

Comment: Thank you for your help GhostGambler

Comment: If you are just trying to generate a random link I think you are really approaching it from the wrong angle. You should aim to just select the one row. You should only do the join on that one row and not everywhere and also not do the or der by rand().  First I'd just get the column of pks as an array and use php to randomly select one of them. Then do the select for just that one.  You should think about really using the API more completely when writing queries, it can help claify things.

Comment: p.s. Would the user ever be doing this inside an unpublished category?  I know why you are checking this, but it seems to structurally no make sense. Also I'd use the router rather than directly using the alias (I assume you have one for your component).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the OR in the ON clause of the join, try using a UNION instead.

```
SELECT a.*, b.category 
FROM #__hdflv_upload a 
INNER JOIN #__hdflv_category b 
ON a.playlistid=b.id 
WHERE a.published='1' AND b.published='1' 
AND b.id=" . $videocategory1 . " 
AND a.id != " .$videoid1 ."  
UNION
SELECT a.*, b.category 
FROM #__hdflv_upload a 
INNER JOIN #__hdflv_category b 
ON a.playlistid=b.parent_id 
WHERE a.published='1' AND b.published='1' 
AND b.id=" . $videocategory1 . " 
AND a.id != " .$videoid1 ." 
ORDER BY RAND()
```

The UNION also removes duplicate records, so rendering the DISTINCT irrelevant.

Note that ORDER BY RAND() can be pretty inefficient. There are more efficient solutions but advising on that would require knowing more about your data (eg, table declares, if id fields are contiguous, etc).